# "Update Failed" whilst downloading application update file

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

A Worklight app on iOS refuses to update, reporting that the "Update Failed. Failed downloading application update file". Curiously, it has been updating over the last couple of weeks. No further information is provided on either the app or the Worklight Console window in Eclipse.

I am using Worklight Studio plugin 5.0.0.27. My iOS device is connected to the Worklight server and the currently installed app works as expected.

How do I extract extra detail from Worklight that describe the symptoms of this failure?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such version as 5.0.0.27. Can you please look at Eclipse >> Help >> Install new software... >> already installed and specify the exact version and build number? (Eclipse >> Help >> About >> Worklight may display an incorrect value...). In addition, can you descrive your development environment and steps you take in order for the direct update to take place? Has the server changed its URL? You can also check in Settings.app >> the Worklight app (scroll to the bottom), if the server URL points to the right location.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance... "IBM Worklight Studio" v 1.0.0.v20120606_0243. Steps to update: 1. Right-click app and select Run As->Build All and Deploy. 2. Confirm the "Application ... deployed successfully with all environments" appears in the Worklight Console log view. 3. Open app on device and observe app update message. What do you need to know about my development environment? The server has not changed its URL. I am unable to find a file called Settings.app.

Comment: Settings.app is the Settings application of your iDevice.

Comment: "Use custom URL" is set to OFF, the AppID is correct and the app version is 1.0.

Comment: To get a little bit more information, have your application connected to the Mac machine and after running it on the device (or simulator) via Xcode, observe the Xcode Console, some more bits of information will be displayed there once the Direct Update failure occurs.

Other than that, does this happen also with a new application, or only with yours? You say that this has started all of a sudden, so it will be interesting to know what has changed...

Comment: Idan, due to time pressures, we've had to redploy the app outside of Worklight (and all is now well). My hope with this question was to identify an in-Worklight process for diagnosing update issues -- a verbose log or similar. At this stage, it is not clear if such a feature exists. Thank you for your assistance and I would be keen to hear of any further insight w.r.t. Worklight's handling of update failures.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion above, the answer to this question is: Unfortunately this is not available at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happens if the app is/was running in the background.

If you double click and find and see a reference to the app, hold down on the icon and shut it off.
Android hold down home, swipe app off.